# Google Cloud Dataflow - Apache Beam - Pipeline Shutdown Hook

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Wondering if there is some kind of "hook" to place a piece of code that would be executed when apache beam pipeline is being shutdown (for whatever reason - crash, cancel)

I need to delete a subscription on pubsub topic each time Dataflow is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam is not naturally suited for this sort of flow. For this you may want to look at an orchestration engine, such as [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/).

With Airflow you should be able to schedule any sort of script to run after a Beam pipeline finishes/fails/is cancelled, etc. Take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of waiting for pipelines to finish and indeed managing Pubsub topics/subscriptions in a [ExampleUtils class in the examples folder in the apache/beam repository here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/common/ExampleUtils.java#L347). See if there is anything you can use in the waitUntilFinish and tearDown methods.

This is java code - not sure if that is the language you use.

(In the long run @Pablo's suggestion to separate this further from the pipeline code may be best - perhaps depends on your exact goal here.)